# Azure OpenAI - built-in policy for Authentication

Tags: azure, azure-openai

There are two methods for authentication listed in the REST API documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/openai/reference

I see that an Azure policy (https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/blob/master/built-in-policies/policyDefinitions/Cognitive%20Services/CognitiveServices_DisableLocalAuth_Audit.json) supports disabling local authentication for the type “Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts”.

I would only like people to use Azure Active Directory authentication. Would I be able to ensure this (AAD) is the only option used with the built-in policy?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as the policy is applied properly it will remediate the resource and disable other authentication methods (such as token). Just make sure that you set the "effect" parameter to "modify".

It's also good to disable public access, and to use a private endpoint. There are additional policies available to accomplish that.